# Drawings disappear after convert from word to pdf with Interop.Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a word file looks like this, it contains some drawings
[Original word file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXjEY.png)

But when I convert this file to pdf, these drawings disappear [Drawing disappear pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scm7H.png)

Here is my code:

```
string path2document = physical_path;
string path2pdf = physical_path.Replace(file_type, ".pdf");
var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(path2document, ReadOnly: true);
var numberOfPages = wordDocument.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path2pdf) == false && numberOfPages <= 100)
{ // Use one of methods below
   wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(path2pdf, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
  // or
   wordDocument.SaveAs2(path2pdf, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
}
if (wordDocument != null)
{
   wordDocument.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
}
if (appWord != null)
{
   appWord.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
   appWord = null;
}
wordDocument.Close();
appWord.Quit();
```

I try to use both **SaveAs2** and **ExportAsFixedFormat**, the result is same, no drawings on pdf file.

Appreciate any help on this. Thank you in advance.

P/s: I use Microsoft Office Profession Plus 2013 on server

Answer (score 0):

Interop usage needs an installed microsoft office in the windows server (or the server you deploy the program).

Interop literally run the mso app in background process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my server is already installed Microsoft Office Profession Plus 2013

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).